# Нарушение корректной работы хука в Delphi

Tags: windows, hook, delphi

Здравствуйте!

У меня происходит нарушение работы хука на мышь на этапе его создания. Проблему я выяснил, но как решить, не могу понять.

В общем, штука такая: есть программа, в которой есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую ставится ловушка на мышь и клавиатуру. С клавиатурой все работает, а вот с мышью — проблема. Как оказалось из анализа работы, хук нарушается тогда, когда во время его создания были совершены действия, который он отслеживает. То есть, если в этой самой программе нажать на эту самую кнопку и начать «шевелить» мышкой (то есть вызывать событие `onmousemove`), то хук ломается. Если же нажать на эту самую кнопку, убрать руки прочь от мыши на несколько секунд и потом уже начать работать, то с хуком порядок! В чем может быть дело? Спасибо... и простите за столь долгую нотацию.

Вот, собственно, функция обработки хука:

```
function wmhook(nCode: Integer; WParam: WPARAM; LParam: LPARAM):LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
    if wparam = WM_LBUTTONDOWN then
    begin
        windows.beep(1000, 100);
        // actions
    end;

    if wparam = WM_RBUTTONDOWN then
    begin
        windows.beep(2000, 100);
        // other actions
    end;

    Result := CallNextHookEx(hh, nCode, WParam, LParam);
end;
```

---

Функция `BlockInput(BOOL);` из `USER32.DLL` спасла!

Answer (score 1):

А почему у Вас нет проверки на nCode < 0? В [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) чётко написано:

> If nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must pass the message
>   to the CallNextHookEx function without further processing and should
>   return the value returned by CallNextHookEx

Т.е. если nCode < 0, никакой дальнейшей обработки быть не должно, кроме возврата результата вызова CallNextHookEx.

А ещё там же написано:

> If the hook procedure processed the message, it may return a nonzero
>   value to prevent the system from passing the message to the target
>   window procedure.

Т.е. можно (нужно) анализировать LPARAM, который указывает на MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT, смотреть какому окну должно отправиться событие и при необходимости предотвращать это.

Answer (score 0):

Вот кусок моего кода из программы. Тоже работа с хуками, посмотри может свою подпрограмму переделаешь. И вопрос, зачем два условия на одно и тоже событие нажатие кнопки мыши?

```
 procedure TForm1.WMICON(var msg: TMessage);
var P : TPoint;
begin
 case msg.LParam of
 WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
  begin
   GetCursorPos(p);
   SetForegroundWindow(Application.MainForm.Handle);
   PopupMenu1.Popup(P.X, P.Y);
  end;
 WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK : N1Click(Self);
 end;
end;
```

Comment: У меня два совершенно разных условия для хука: для нажатия левой  и правой кнопок мыши! Будьте чуток повнимательнее =) А ваш код вообще здесь неуместен! Ваш код обрабатывает событие, когда по иконке приложения, свернутому в системный трей, произошел клик или двойной клик! Так, например, на одинарный клик всплывает меню, а на двойной клик происходит клик по главному меню... Не пойму, зачем вы выложили свой код.....

Comment: Все заметил, что разные клавиши обрабатываете. Выложил свой код, думая, что совсем не варите в этом вопросе. Работал с хуками, с такой, как у вас проблемой не встречался.

Comment: И что, можно теперь выкладывать все, что в голову взбредет? Что же вы не выложили один из томов Л.Н Толстого "Война и мир" ?